# Generate UML from Java source

Tags: java, netbeans, uml, code-generation

Because I have a big project I must generate the UML for this. Writing UML for 300 classes is overkill.

So is there any solution to generate the diagrams for me?

P.S.
I am using Netbeans.

Comment: You are aware that the UML diagrams are going to be totally incomprehensible? With 300 classes, you're going to be drowning in detail.

Comment: check this 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/reverse-engineer-source-code-u

Comment: I know that it is going to be totally incomprehensible but i aint going to generate everything..
For example a class diagramm would be ok.. 
Writing from scratch again each method and field is really boring and waste of time

Comment: rational rose has or could batchmode OK result

Comment: You don't need a batchmode !! I did the job with 5000 classes and the first reverse is long (e.g. about 30 mn) then navigation is immediate. You should change tools and not to use Rational when a java project.

Comment: A complete UML model is useful for fully implementing a model as a program. A complete UML model of an already implemented program is next to useless for understanding that program.

Comment: They want all the available UML diagrams:( i know that noone implements all of them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending what you need the UML diagrams for, you might want to extract the concepts out of your "300 classes" and make the UML diagrams yourself- it probably helps finding architectural flaws also. 
Mass converting Code to UML just for the purpose to have UML is usually not very desirable.

If you really need it, yes Enterprise Architect is a good way to go. - classic.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) by sparxx systems can create UML from Java classes

Answer (score 1):

Try http://netbeans.org/features/uml/ It supports Reverse Engineering of code. Of course all you are going to get is Class Diagrams.

Comment: Note: this is not free.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using Sybase Power Designer because it supports all types of UML diagrams. Please see wikipedia at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerDesigner

PS: *I am neither advertising nor associated with this company, but Power Designer has several features that I am fond of.*

Answer (score 0):

I found easyUML useful. It's really easy to use.